# rails server won't start because ActiveAdmin Comment change

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm trying to start a rails app (4.1.8), using activeadmin version from gregbell/activeadmin in my Gemfile.  On startup rails first complained "`config.allow_comments` is no longer provided in ActiveAdmin 1.x. Use `config.comments` instead. (RuntimeError)"  So I changed to config.comments in active_admin.rb, tried to restart and now I get:

```
You're trying to register ActiveAdmin::Comment as Comment, but the existing ActiveAdmin::Resource config was built for Comment! (ActiveAdmin::ResourceCollection::ConfigMismatch)
```

What gives, anyone see this before and know how to fix it?  Seems like there's no change in active_admin and now suddenly this.

Many Thanks for any advice.

**UPDATE:**

For anyone with the same issue, I solved it by changing the activeadmin Comment class like this:

```
change
ActiveAdmin.register Comment do


to this
ActiveAdmin.register Comment, as: "UserComment" do
```

as mentioned in the comments here: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/301

Answer (score 0):

...posting my own answer to this question...   I had to change the signature of the activeadmin Comment class as mentioned in my update above.  It came from the comments here: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/301